# Find and replace a portion of text in a field using MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace, find, redundancy

I have a table with a column containing text that include the following string:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" src="http://adsense-google.ru/js/XYZ.js"></script>
```

Where `XYZ` can be a random text such as `37a90a1fe7512a804347fa3e572c6b86`

How could I remove everything between and including the `<script>` tags using plain MySQL?

Comment: You should probably just delete phpmyadmin entirely and reinstall it, just to be safe.

Comment: find table where post is , in phpmyadmin, and update table column using like.

Comment: Hamza Kubba, thanks for advice, that would be the best way to clean thing up but in my database I have over 30,000 article posts, this would be big problem

Comment: developerCK, yes that would be only choice I have and Mosty Mostacho jsut gave me perfect solution below...thanks you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to replace a non-fixed string you should use the delimiters of the string you want to replace. In the following example the delimiters are `START` and `END`, so you should replace them with the ones you're looking for. I've included both options: with and without the delimiters replaced.

Sample data assuming a table `t` with a column `col`:

```
|                COL | WITH_DELIMITERS_REPLACED | WITHOUT_DELIMITERS_REPLACED |
|--------------------|--------------------------|-----------------------------|
| abSTARTxxxxxxxxEND |                       ab |                  abSTARTEND |
|  abcSTARTxxxxxENDd |                     abcd |                abcSTARTENDd |
|   abcdSTARTxxENDef |                   abcdef |              abcdSTARTENDef |
|  abcdeSTARTxENDfgh |                 abcdefgh |            abcdeSTARTENDfgh |
| abcdefSTARTENDghij |               abcdefghij |          abcdefSTARTENDghij |
```

This is the query that creates the previous output from the `col` column. Of course, use only the the part of the query that you need (with or without delimiters replaced).

```
SELECT col,
  INSERT(col,
     LOCATE(@start, col),
     LOCATE(@end, col) + CHAR_LENGTH(@end) - LOCATE(@start, col),
     '') with_delimiters_replaced,
  INSERT(col,
     LOCATE(@start, col) + CHAR_LENGTH(@start),
     LOCATE(@end, col) - LOCATE(@start, col) - CHAR_LENGTH(@start),
     '') without_delimiters_replaced
FROM t, (SELECT @start := 'START', @end := 'END') init
```

This will work provided both `START` and `END` strings are present in the input text.

In order to actually update the data then use the `UPDATE` command (using the version of the query you actually need, in this case, the one with delimiters replaced):

```
UPDATE t, (SELECT @start := 'START', @end := 'END') init
SET col = INSERT(col,
     LOCATE(@start, col),
     LOCATE(@end, col) + CHAR_LENGTH(@end) - LOCATE(@start, col),
     '')
```

In your particular case replace `START` with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" src="http://adsense-google.ru/js/
```

and `END` with:

```
.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is incredible A++++

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Mosty Mostacho and angel koilov for your answers...I see the update option from Mosty Mostacho is very effective method...you are life saver!

Thank you.

Update:
**Mosty Mostacho** your "update" method is absolutely 100% works! Than kyou very very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could download backup of production db.
Restore it on your local machine.
You don't need preg* plugin on production server. That is why we do all stuff local. Install some preg* plugin for mysql (like https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg)
Do your stuff.
Restore cleaned db to production